# Daily getting :: SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys:

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-identity, owin, openid-connect

I have vb.net application and i am facing this IDX10501: Signature validation failed.  Unable to match keys: issue. My code work fine for 10-12 hours but after that i start getting this issue .But as soon as i re-save the config without changing anything it start working .Then after 10-12 hours i start facing the same issue. I guess it is something related to signing keys. Any help would be appreciated. I am using OpenAthens.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect to implement . Also even when i am getting this error , i am getting Kid and token values correctly.
**Startup.vb file**

```
Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports OpenAthens.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin


Public Class ExpectedJwksResponse
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="keys")>
    Public Property Keys As List(Of JsonWebKey)
End Class

Public Class Startup


    Private ReadOnly clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ClientId")
    Private ReadOnly authority As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("OrgUri")
    Private ReadOnly clientSecret As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ClientSecret")
    Private ReadOnly redirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RedirectUri")
    Private ReadOnly callBackPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CallBackPath")
    Private ReadOnly acr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Acr")
    Private ReadOnly acrValues As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AcrValues")




    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        ConfigureAuth(app)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim configurationManager = New ConfigurationManager(Of OpenIdConnectConfiguration)(
        $"{authority}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        New OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(), New HttpDocumentRetriever())

        Dim discoveryDocument = configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result
        Dim signingKeys = GetSecurityKeyAsync(discoveryDocument.JwksUri).Result
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = True

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = True,
            .ClientId = clientId,
            .ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            .Authority = authority,
            .ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .CallbackPath = Microsoft.Owin.PathString.FromUriComponent(New Uri(callBackPath)),
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
               .IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys,
                .RequireSignedTokens = True,
                .RequireExpirationTime = True,
                .ValidateLifetime = True,
                .ValidateAudience = True,
                .ValidAudience = clientId,
                .ValidateIssuer = True,
                .ValidIssuer = authority,
                .SaveSigninToken = True
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(n)
                                                  n.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(acr, acrValues)
                                                  n.Response.Redirect(callBackPath)
                                                  n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = callBackPath
                                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                              End Function,
                .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                                              Dim anc = Convert.ToString(context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken)
                                              Dim rawAccessToken As String = context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken
                                              Dim rawIdToken As String = context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken
                                              Dim handler = New JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
                                              Dim accessToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(rawAccessToken)
                                              Dim idToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(rawIdToken)
                                              context.Response.Redirect(callBackPath)

                                              If (TypeOf context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity Is ClaimsIdentity) Then
                                                  Dim identity As ClaimsIdentity = New ClaimsIdentity
                                                  Dim claimsIdentity As ClaimsIdentity = CType(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity, ClaimsIdentity)
                                                  Dim userId As String = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
                                                  identity.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, userId))
                                              End If

                                              Return Task.CompletedTask
                                          End Function
            }
        })
    End Sub

    Private Async Function GetSecurityKeyAsync(ByVal jwksUri As String) As Task(Of List(Of SecurityKey))
        Using client = New HttpClient()
            Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(New Uri(jwksUri))

            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim result = Await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(Of ExpectedJwksResponse)()
                Dim keys = New List(Of SecurityKey)()
                Dim i = 0
                For Each key In result.Keys
                    keys.Add(key)
                    i = i + 1
                Next
                Return keys
            End If
        End Using

        Return Nothing
    End Function

End Class
```

**Challenge  :**

```
   HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(New AuthenticationProperties With {
        .RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RedirectUri")}, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
```

Comment: What authorization server are you using? do you see this in production or locally during development?

Comment: This never comes in locally env but coming in dev , stage and prod. Auth server is our internal company auth server.

Answer (score 0):

In production, you need to address a few different issues:

1. The IdentityServer [token signing key](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/keys/) must be configured and stored outside your service, so that it is the same during redeployment.
2. The [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in every ASP.NET Core service needs to be configured so that the encryption key and key-ring is persisted. So that it is the same during redeployments. You need to do this so that all issued cookies are accepted after redeployment.

Comment: could not understand it ? My application doesnt require redeployment . Even after i restart the app it start working.

Comment: one thing is to monitor the keys here, are they the same all the time or do they change after 10-12h? https://youridentityserver/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

Comment: How is it deployed in production?

Comment: It is changing from auth server but i am not able to get the latest key everytime. Whenever app start first time on server , it get the keys. I am unable to find way, how to get new key from server . As this challenge method , not calling that step which get the sign key.

Comment: if you in your startup class in production have this statement "AddDeveloperSigningCredential()" , then you need to do some work.

Comment: NO i do not have that. I have provided the code as well of startup class. Please check that

Comment: do you have multiple auth services?  Perhaps the access-token is expired and you need to refresh it (get a new one) using the refresh token? This is something you most of the time need to add support for by your self.  There are various support code available in the IdentityModel library https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: i have implemented it in vb.net and maintaining session. So from auth server , i am just taking claims.

Comment: perhaps you need to review the lifetime of the session cookie that you get, check in the browser or using a tool like Fiddler and see what the lifetime of it is.